# MAMP Mysql in Terminal

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I've installed MAMP on my MacBook PRO Leopard OS. Phpmyadmin is working fine but I would like to use the terminal or bash to practice MySQL.

I seem to have a problem with it.

When I use:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p" / "mysql -h localhost -u root"
```

...it gives the following error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES/NO)

Please suggest any solutions possible! Thanx in advance. :)

Comment: Try checking the first page you get when you login with phpmyadmin, what credentials/host is it login in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the first page you get when you login with phpmyadmin, what credentials/host is it login in? – Francisco Soto 2 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

I have created aliases in my .bash_profile:

```
alias mysql='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql'
alias mysqldump='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump'
```

I hope this helps.